# can not access superclass method from within subclass that implements comparator

Tags: java, subclass, comparator, superclass

I am attempting to use the slopeTo method inside my slopeCompare subclass in my comparator definition. However I get an error in eclipse telling me to change slopeTo to a static method. It also does not work when I use this.slopeTo(). I thought that the whole point of subclasses was that they can use all the methods of the superclass. Can someone help me clarify what I am not understanding here? I apologize if I am misusing terminology but comparators are a new topic and I am not entirely comfortable with them.

(this is from the princeton algorithms course on udacity)

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdDraw;

public class Point implements Comparable<Point> {

    private final int x;     // x-coordinate of this point
    private final int y;     // y-coordinate of this point

    /**
     * Initializes a new point.
     *
     * @param  x the <em>x</em>-coordinate of the point
     * @param  y the <em>y</em>-coordinate of the point
     */
    public Point(int x, int y) {
        /* DO NOT MODIFY */
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    /**
     * Draws this point to standard draw.
     */
    public void draw() {
        /* DO NOT MODIFY */
        StdDraw.point(x, y);
    }

    /**
     * Draws the line segment between this point and the specified point
     * to standard draw.
     *
     * @param that the other point
     */
    public void drawTo(Point that) {
        /* DO NOT MODIFY */
        StdDraw.line(this.x, this.y, that.x, that.y);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the slope between this point and the specified point.
     * Formally, if the two points are (x0, y0) and (x1, y1), then the slope
     * is (y1 - y0) / (x1 - x0). For completeness, the slope is defined to be
     * +0.0 if the line segment connecting the two points is horizontal;
     * Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY if the line segment is vertical;
     * and Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY if (x0, y0) and (x1, y1) are equal.
     *
     * @param  that the other point
     * @return the slope between this point and the specified point
     */
    public double slopeTo(Point that) {
        /* YOUR CODE HERE */
        if (this.compareTo(that) == 0){
            return Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
        }
        double slope = (double)(that.y-this.y)/(that.x-this.x);

        return slope;
    }

    /**
     * Compares two points by y-coordinate, breaking ties by x-coordinate.
     * Formally, the invoking point (x0, y0) is less than the argument point
     * (x1, y1) if and only if either y0 < y1 or if y0 = y1 and x0 < x1.
     *
     * @param  that the other point
     * @return the value <tt>0</tt> if this point is equal to the argument
     *         point (x0 = x1 and y0 = y1);
     *         a negative integer if this point is less than the argument
     *         point; and a positive integer if this point is greater than the
     *         argument point
     */
    public int compareTo(Point that) {
        if (this.y > that.y){
            return 1;
        }
        if (this.y < that.y){
            return -1;
        }
        if ((this.y == that.y) && (this.x < that.x)){
            return -1;
        }
        if ((this.y == that.y) && (this.x > that.x)){
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }

    }

    /**
     * Compares two points by the slope they make with this point.
     * The slope is defined as in the slopeTo() method.
     *
     * @return the Comparator that defines this ordering on points
     */
    public Comparator<Point> slopeOrder() {
        /* YOUR CODE HERE */

        return new SlopeCompare();

    }

    private static class SlopeCompare implements Comparator<Point> {
        public int compare(Point a, Point b){
            if (slopeTo(a) < slopeTo(b)){
                return -1;
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }


    /**
     * Returns a string representation of this point.
     * This method is provide for debugging;
     * your program should not rely on the format of the string representation.
     *
     * @return a string representation of this point
     */
    public String toString() {
        /* DO NOT MODIFY */
        return "(" + x + ", " + y + ")";
    }

    /**
     * Unit tests the Point data type.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* YOUR CODE HERE */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` in `this.slopeTo()` represents `SlopeCompare` instance, inner class can indeed access fields and methods of outer class, but it's not inherit, so you can not access `slopeTo()` with `this` keywords, you can ues `outer.this` to get an instance of the outer class.

Two solutions for references:

1.define `slopeTo()` method with `static`:

```
public static double slopeTo(Point that) {
```

2.remove the `static` keywords from the member class:

```
private class SlopeCompare implements Comparator<Point> {
```

Comment: This is indeed one way to fix it, but it doesn't explain what the problem is in the first place.

Comment: I am pretty sure it must be static based on the constraints in the project outline. But that makes me think I am just going about solving the problem incorrectly.

Comment: Actually I think you might be correct. I came across a similar answer in the courses forums and it sounded like it worked out for them. Ill give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't comment yet.

But yes, you cannot call non static method inside static method. 
Static belongs to class and non-static belongs to the instance you can look more into that in google.

If SlopeCompare should be static you need to have an instance of Point to call slopeTo.

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure how I didn't notice this. What I am still confused about is why I can't use "this". I was under the impression that this.slopeTo(a) is the same thing as slopeTo(a).